# Confusion about this simple electrostatics line integral

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, voltage, integration

Suppose we want to find the electrostatic potential $\phi_{0}$, with reference to infinity, at $r_{0}$ resulting from a positive charge $q$ located at the origin. For simplicity, let us assume we are working in two dimensions.

[image]
By definition $\phi _{0}$ is the work per unit charge required to bring a  positive test charge that is very far away to the vicinity of $r_{0}$.

$$\phi_{0}=\int_{\infty}^{r_{0}}-\textbf{E}\cdot\textbf{dl}$$

decomposing $\textbf{dl}$ into two orthogonal vectors $$\textbf{dl}=\textbf{dr}+\textbf{dr}_{\perp}$$

the integral becomes

$$\phi_{0}=\int_{\infty}^{r_{0}}-\textbf{E}\cdot \textbf{dr}$$
We define $\hat{\textbf{r}}$ as the unit vector pointing radially away from $q$. 
 $\textbf{E}$ will be expressed as

$$\textbf{E}=\frac{q}{r^{2}}\hat{\textbf{r}}$$

and $\textbf{dr}$ as $$\textbf{dr}= \textrm{dr} \, \hat {\textbf{r}}$$

where, and I think this is important, $\textrm{r}$ starts from $\infty$ and goes all the way down to $r_{0}$, in other words, $\textrm{r}$ is decreasing, thereby making $\textbf{dr}$ point in the $-\hat{\textbf{r}}$ direction.

Going back to our integral

$$\phi _{0}= \int_{\infty}^{r_{0}}\frac{q}{r^2}\hat{\textbf{r}}\cdot \textrm{dr}\,\hat{\textbf{r}}$$
$$=\int_{\infty}^{r_{0}}\frac{q}{r^2}\textrm{dr}$$

In its final form 
$$\phi_{0}=-\frac{q}{r_{0}}$$

This result must certainly be incorrect since the potential ought to be positive. I suspect it is because of the way I set up $\textbf{dr}$, but I can't precisely pinpoint the incorrect step in the reasoning. Since $r$ is ranging from $\infty$ down to $0$, then $\textrm{dr} <0$, thus $\textbf{dr}$ is pointing in the correct direction. Where does the error lie in?

Comment: What happened to the negative sign from the original integral ?

Comment: R.W.Bird Thank you. This is definitely one of the silliest posts I've ever made. Would it preferable to remove it?

Comment: A quibble:  You said that potential is equal to the work done to move a charge in from infinity.  But your first equation is the work done by the electrostatic force, with a minus sign added.  The distinction can make a difference if one is not very careful when there are multiple forces involved, especially if one or more of them is non-conservative.   It's safer, and arguably "more correct", not to mentions any forces other than the electrostatic force.  Why add external forces when they are not necessary for the argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm attempting to answer your question, I hope you may find it convincing.
(I will refer my explanation to this image, yellow arrows are the field lines going away from the charge and dl is coming inward) [image]
 If we write the equation of the potential as given in **Griffiths:Introduction to Electrodynamics** $$ V(r) = - \int_{O}^{r} \mathbf{E} \cdot d\mathbf{l}$$ If we try to write the meaning of this equation in words, then:
*Potential is the negative of the work done by the electric field to move a unit charge from a standard point O to r*
Let's do some maths now, $$V(r)= - \int_{O}^{r} E~dl~cos{180}^0 $$
$$V(r)= - \int_{O}^{r} -E~dl$$
$$V(r)= \int_{O}^{r} E~dl$$
Now let's try to write the meaning of this last equation in words , then: 
*Potential is the work done by the electric field to move a unit charge from a standard point O to r*
See, both the definitions are contradicting each other, this contradiction has occurred because we assumed $d\mathbf{l}$ to be in negative direction of **E**. Actually, when we write $$ -\int_{O}^{r} \mathbf{E} \cdot d\mathbf{l}$$ we mean that the negative of the work that our **E** will do on a unit charge to move it from a standard point to $r$, there it is implied by the minus sign that **E** and direction of motion are quite opposite. The founder/s of that equation put that minus sign so as to ensure that **E** will do a negative work when a charge is brought from a standard point to $r$ and therefore we need not to consider the direction of d$\mathbf{l}$ to be opposite of **E**.
Some people get frightened by the minus sign that appears in the potential equation $$ \Delta U = - W_{by~ the~ field}$$ the minus sign is there because it was assumed (when equations were developed) that field lines always go away from the charged object/mass and hence whenever a unit charge/mass is brought close it the field always gonna do the negative work.

Hope it will convince you! I know the feeling of confusion is very painful, Feynaman too had this feeling of [confusion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lytxafTXg6c).

Answer (score 0):

> I think this is important, $\textrm{r}$ starts from $\infty$ and goes all the way down to $r_{0}$, in other words, $\textrm{r}$ is decreasing, thereby making $\textbf{dr}$ point in the $-\hat{\textbf{r}}$ direction.

You're adding one too many minus signs here.  If your lower integral bound is larger than your upper integral bound, then $dr$ is inherently negative, and so $\mathbf{dr} = dr \mathbf{\hat r} = -|dr|\mathbf{\hat r}$ is *already* pointing along $-\mathbf{\hat r}$.

To avoid confusion, you can use the minus sign at the beginning to flip the integral bounds:

$$\int_\infty^{r_0} -\mathbf{E}\cdot \mathbf{dr} = \int_{r_0}^\infty \mathbf E\cdot \mathbf{dr} = \int_{r_0}^\infty \frac{q}{r^2} dr = \left. -\frac{q}{r}\right|^\infty_{r_0} = \frac{q}{r_0}$$

Answer (score 0):

Potential difference is negative of the work done by internal electric force on a unit positive charge to move it from reference point to desired point.$$\begin{align}\overbrace{-\underbrace{(V_{\infty}-V_{r_0})}_{\frac{W_{r_0\rightarrow\infty}}{q_0}}}^{\Delta V}&=\int_{r_0}^\infty \vec{E}\cdot\vec{dr}\\&=\int_{r_0}^\infty \dfrac{kq}{r^2}dr\\&=\bigg(-\dfrac{kq}{r}\bigg)^{\infty}_{r_0}\\&=\dfrac{kq}{r} \end{align}$$